# PHP / HTML textarea string regexp (regular expression)

Tags: php, html, string, preg-replace

**Background**

In Wordpress there is a function called [wpautop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop). It adds paragraphs an br-tags automatically on output.

**Problem**

I have a textarea inside a **$content** string and I don't want auto formatting inside that textarea. The might be more than one textarea in the string.

**Example string - before wpautop**

```
This is my text. My paragraph.
<textarea class="test">
    &lt;html&gt;Code test&lt;/html&gt;
</textarea>
```

**Example string - after wpautop**

```
<p>This is my text. My paragraph</p>
<textarea class="test">
    <br />
    &lt;html&gt;Code test&lt;/html&gt;<br />
</textarea>
```

**Possible solutions**

1. Somehow create an array with all the textareas in the string. Run wpautop and insert them back again into the string.
2. Don't use wpautop. Use a new regexp for it instead.

Comment: I'm not familiar with wordpress, but what's the `<html>` tag doing inside a `textarea`?

Comment: That is also a thing worth mentioning.

Comment: It's for presenting code, but it should have been &lt;html&gt;.

Answer (score 1):

```
$splited=preg_split('#<textarea.*?</textarea>#s', $text, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

for ($i=0; $i<count($splited); $i+=2)
     $splited[$i]=wpatoup($splited[$i]);

echo implode('', $splited);
```

1. Split string where are textareas.
2. Now you know that every secondth element is not a textarea. Apply wpatoup() to it.
3. Join back again.

Comment: That did not work. A var_dump gives only the whole string in [0].

Comment: Edited. Notice that s after #.

Answer (score 1):

**Cheeck this out it would be much helpful**

```
    $textareas = '<textarea>
                    <html>Code test1</html>
                   </textarea>
                   <textarea class="test1">
                   <html>Code test2</html>
                   </textarea>
                   <textarea class="test3">
                   <html>Code test3</html>
                   </textarea>
                   <textarea class="test4">
                   <html>Code test4</html>
                   </textarea>';
error_reporting(E_ERROR|E_PARSE);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($textareas);

$xml  = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$data  = $xml->xpath('//textarea');
foreach($data as $key=>$value):
    echo $data[$key][$key+1]."<br/>";
endforeach;
```

Comment: I got an error "<b>Warning</b>:  DOMDocument::loadHTML() [<a href='domdocument.loadhtml'>domdocument.loadhtml</a>]: htmlParseStartTag: misplaced &lt;html&gt; tag in Entity"

Comment: @JensTörnell Check this out now,, i have edited and now it works fine